# gap between a div and the top of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with a gap between the `div` "name" and the top of the screen. I've done some research and all I can find is `margin` which I have already set and `position: absolute;` that messes up with the position of the div.The gap wasn't here earlier and I don't know what I did to make it appear.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("./console.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.name {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h1> Clovis Sargenton Callard </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The `h1` inside `name` probably has some margin associated with it. Try setting that to 0. eg `h1 { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [collapsing margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

Remove the top margin on your `h1` to create the effect you want.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("./console.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.name {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h1> Clovis Sargenton Callard </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin: 0` on your `h1` element.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("./console.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.name {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h1> Clovis Sargenton Callard </h1>
</div>
```